# Getting weird output

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Hello I am trying to use retrofit everything is fine. But I am getting output like this.
[examples.sewoyebah.com.retrofit.model.Model@41ce7408, examples.sewoyebah.com.retrofit.model.Model@41ce7698]

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Bind(R.id.activity_main_tv_display)
TextView textData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

@OnClick(R.id.activity_main_btn_show)

void press() {
    RemoteApi.Factory.getInstance().getModel().enqueue(new Callback<List<Model>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Model>> call, Response<List<Model>> response) {
            textData.setText(String.valueOf(response.body()));
            Log.e("--success--", String.valueOf(response.body()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Model>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("--fail--", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
}
```

This is my model

```
public class Model {

@SerializedName("Title")
@Expose
private String Title;
@SerializedName("Message")
@Expose
private String Message;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private int id;
// getters and setters declare
}
```

Here is my interface

```
public interface RemoteApi {

String BASE_URL = "xyz/";
@GET("api/Cards")
Call<List<Model>> getModel();
class Factory {
    public static RemoteApi remoteApi;
    public static RemoteApi getInstance() {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .build();
            remoteApi = retrofit.create(RemoteApi.class);
            return remoteApi;
        }
    }
}
```

And My API looks like this

```
[{
  "Title": "xyz",
  "Message": "hello",
  "id": 1
}, {
  "Title": "abc",
  "Message": "hello",
  "id": 2
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct,

```
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Model>> call, Response<List<Model>> response) {
        textData.setText(String.valueOf(response.body()));
        Log.e("--success--", String.valueOf(response.body()));
    }
```

the body you're reading here in the response is a list of Model objects.
You should probably iterate this list if you want to get the title and message values.

**Edit**
You can iterate like this:

```
public void onResponse(Call<List<Model>> call, Response<List<Model>> response) {
    for (Model eachModel : response.body())
    {
        Log.e("--success--", eachModel.title);
    }
}
```

This will output to the console the title of each element. You may need to create a list, or refactor your textview code if you want to display all titles in a textview.

Comment: Done. Why the -1 ?

Comment: Ooops, sorry. It should be response.body()